# Gradient and Rate of Maximum Increase

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

So I have an applied gradient problem that I seem to be stuck on.

Given the function z = x + xy, I want to find the direction of maximum increase at any point. Then, I want to know, at any point, whether to add 2 to x or 0.01 to y in order to get the maximum increase. I can only add 2 to x or 0.01 to y, not both, and not any other value for either. I must choose to add one or the other at any point.

Now, I have found the gradient and its unit vector, but the resultant vectors don't seem to make sense for what I want to find out. I assumed the magnitude of the i and j components in relation to each other tells me whether to add to x or y, but that seems to contradict with numerical testing.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I did something wrong somewhere.

Comment: Is this explicitly a problem involving the best linear approximation of the graph of z=x+xy?  Can you clarify what you mean by "maximum increase"?  Are you looking for the magnitude of the gradient vector of g(x,y,z):=z-x-xy?  Or are you looking for the increase in height of the linear approximation to the graph of z=x+xy in the direction of the gradient?

Comment: So the surface of z = x + xy in the domain and range I'm interested in looks like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5Bz%3Dx%2Bxy%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+2000%7D%2C+%7By%2C0%2C10%7D%5D

I want to know how to get up the hill as quickly as possible at any point on the hill. Problem is at any given point, per turn, I can only move in the x direction 2 units OR y direction 0.01 units, not both. I must choose. I want to know which one to choose at any point on the hill if I want to get to the top as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's canonical that the way to proceed up the hill as quickly as possible is to follow the gradient.  For the purposes of this problem, however, we aren't allowed to do that.  We are only allowed to proceed 2 units in the positive x-direction or 0.5 units in the positive y-direction.  I'm assuming, for simplicity's sake, that we are measuring these distances not on the surface but along the coordinate lines in the xy-plane "below" the surface (which we view as embedded in $\mathbf{R}^{3}$).

This means that, instead of $\nabla{g}=(-1-y,-x,1)$ being the direction in which we proceed at point $(x,y,x+xy)$, we proceed in either the direction $(1,0,1)$ or the direction $(0,1,0)$.  These last two vectors are the tangent vectors to the images under $g$ of the coordinate curves in the xy-plane: $g(t,0)=(t,0,t)$ and $g(0,t)=(0,t,0)$.

Now, my first thought is: for each choice of point $(x_{0},y_{0})$, compare the dot product expressions $$\nabla{g}(x_{0},y_{0},x_{0}+x_{0}y_{0})\cdot \frac{(1,0,1)}{\sqrt{2}}, \hspace{0.5cm} \mbox{and} \hspace{0.5cm} \nabla{g}(x_{0},y_{0},x_{0}+x_{0}y_{0})\cdot (0,1,0)$$ If we divide both expressions by the norm of the gradient at $(x_{0},y_{0},x_{0}+x_{0}y_{0})$, then we obtain the cosines of the angles between the gradient vector and the two coordinate vectors.  Simple computation shows that the first expression is smaller than the second if and only if $$y_{0}>\sqrt{2}x_{0}$$  Since the cosine function is decreasing monotonically on the interval $[0,\pi]$, this tells us that in the region $\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^{2}|y>\sqrt{2}x\}$ of the xy-plane above the line $y=\sqrt{2}x$, the angle between $\nabla{g}(x_{0},y_{0},x_{0}+x_{0}y_{0})$ and $(1,0,1)$ is larger than the one between $\nabla{g}(x_{0},y_{0},x_{0}+x_{0}y_{0})$ and $(0,1,0)$, and so it would make sense to proceed in the direction of $(0,1,0)$... that is, to go purely in the y-direction, since in this case, the angle is "closer" to the gradient.  In the region $\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^{2}|y<\sqrt{2}x\}$, the opposite would be true, and so it would make sense to go purely in the x-direction.  On the line $y=\sqrt{2}x$, there is no difference between the two angles.

I said this was my first idea.  I'm not sure it is what Ray's instructor/textbook is expecting as an answer, because you'll notice that except when I used the cosine angle formula above, I did not respect the problem element that one may move only a certain amount in the x-direction or only a certain amount in the y-direction.

My second idea is this: consider the paths $$c_{(x_{0},y_{0})}(t):=(x_{0},y_{0})+t\left(\frac{-1-y_{0}}{\sqrt{1+x_{0}^{2}+(1+y_{0})^{2}}},\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1+x_{0}^{2}+(1+y_{0})^{2}}}\right)$$ $$c_{1}(t):=(x_{0}+2t,y_{0})$$ $$c_{2}(t):=(x_{0},y_{0}+\frac{1}{2}t)$$ in the xy-plane, for $0\leq t\leq 1$.  In one unit of time, $c_{i}(t)$ will take either 2 "steps" in the x-direction or 0.5 "steps" in the y-direction.  Plug these curves into the function $g(x,y)=(x,y,x+xy)$, and get three curves on the surface.  Then, compute and compare $$||g(c_{1}(1))-g(c_{(x_{0},y_{0})}(1))||^{2}$$ with $$||g(c_{2}(1))-g(c_{(x_{0},y_{0})}(1))||^{2}$$  If the first is smaller, then that tells you that $g(c_{1}(1))$ is closer to $g(c_{(x_{0},y_{0})}(1))$, i.e., that going 2 "steps" in the x-direction along the surface will get you closer to the point on the surface where you'd arrive you traveled in the direction of the gradient for on unit of time, and vice versa if the second norm-squared is smaller.

Or, perhaps, you just need to take the three curves $g\circ c_{1}(t)$ annd $g\circ c_{2}(t)$, and compare their z-coordinates at time $t=1$ in order to see which one is highest.

I think I may need to understand more about the problem from Ray's end before conjecturing more.